# Unable to build AWS SQS Connector (V1.0.7) by using Apache Maven 3.8.4

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, aws-sqs-fifo, wso2-esb

I want to edit SendMessage Operation Code in existing AWS SQS Connector(V1.0.7) and wanna to build this editable connector and use it in WSO2 EI 6.4.0.

**Reason to edit existing Code:**
Unable to post incoming payload into AWS SQS Queue often. For more reference [click here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-amazonsqs/issues/27)

**Steps I followed:**

- I just downloaded AWS SQS Connector (V1.0.7) from [GitHub](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-amazonsqs/tree/org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazonsqs-1.0.7) by using Download Zip Option.
- after unzipping it, i did `mvn clean install` by navigate to directory called "esb-connector-amazonsqs-org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazonsqs-1.0.7"
- Build Successful by using Apache maven 3.8.4 and got zip file inside "target" directory.
- I have taken that zip file and unzipped it to add below code in Send Operation

**Just adding Endpoint Timeout Error handling to existing http call.**

```
<http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.apiUrl}{+uri.var.httpRequestUri}">
<timeout>
<duration>60000</duration>
</timeout>
<suspendOnFailure>
<errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
<initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
<progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
<maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
</suspendOnFailure>
<markForSuspension>
<retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
</markForSuspension>
</http>
```

- After adding above code, I tried 2 ways.
- i made it as zip file and one way is place that into target directory and did same
  maven build again once build successful. Modified code not exist when i review again, only existing code available, in SendMessage Operation
- Another way is i directly used modified zip code and place it inside server(Connectors-->Add) which leads to below issue, Connector deployment is unsuccessful.

ERROR LOG:

```
[2022-01-21 12:25:05,159] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer} - Deployment of synapse artifact failed for synapse libray at : C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.6.0\wso2ei-6.6.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7.zip : Error while extracting Synapse Library : amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7.zip org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while extracting Synapse Library : amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7.zip
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:426)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.createSynapseLibrary(LibDeployerUtils.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer.deploy(LibraryArtifactDeployer.java:60)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Development_Avecto\WSo2EIServers\wso2ei-6.6.0\wso2ei-6.6.0\bin\..\wso2\tmp\libs\1642748105152amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7.zip\amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7\amazonSQS-config\component.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extract(LibDeployerUtils.java:469)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:424)
```

I know that this is not the right way to do it.

Can any WSO2 Experts guide me the way to edit existing connector code ,building it as connector in order to use the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved above connector build issue and Now I can use custom built AWS SQS connector(V1.07) in WSO2 EI Server.

Steps:

- Open `sendMessage.xml` operation file directory `esb-connector-amazonsqs-org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazonsqs-1.0.7\src\main\resources\amazonSQS-message`
- modified section like below.
  [image: modifified code]
- again goto directory `esb-connector-amazonsqs-org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazonsqs-1.0.7` where `pom.xml` resides
- run `mvn clean install` in above directory.
- after build successful, we can get `amazonsqs-connector-1.0.7.zip` file inside directory `esb-connector-amazonsqs-org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazonsqs-1.0.7\target`